# Android HTML5 Camera Access Not working

Tags: android, asp.net-mvc, html, camera, android-camera

I have been stuck on this problem for days and cannot seem to find a solution.  Basically I am using the following to capture an image inside a form, based on my research the  line below should access the android device camera and allow the user to take and capture a picture.  In fact this code does work exactly as expected when running from the web browser on my android device, however when I try to run it from the app it simply grays out the button and never pulls up the camera.  The website related to this app uses ASP.Net MVC5 in case that helps.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="form-group">
            <!-- 1132 - Here we enter the BOL Number as well as a button to take an image of the BOL -->
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.BOLNumber)
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.BOLNumber, new {@class = "form-control"})
            <input type="file" id="BOLImage" name="BOLImage" accept="image/*" capture="camera">
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.BOLNumber)          
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I have also ensured that the app has the appropriate permissions in the AndroidManifest.xml and confirmed that the app does have camera permission once loaded see below:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />    
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_GPS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_ASSISTED_GPS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_DOWNLOAD_MANAGER"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />
```

Can anyone help me with this frustrating problem?

Comment: Hey Aaron. If this is an Android problem, or programming question please reask your question on [Android Stackoverflow](http://android.stackoverflow.com)

Comment: This is more of a programming question as I am basically unsure if I am missing something codewise, but I will go check out the android stackoverflow as well

Comment: I just looked and the android stack overflow covers user questions so I'm pretty sure this question belongs here on stackoverflow